# PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR: function count(bigint, integer) does not exist in rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pgadmin-4

I have two models Product and Order have a relation between them belongs to product and has_many orders.

```
#app/models/product.rb
class Product < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :orders, dependent: :destroy
end
```

```
#app/models/order.rb
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product

  enum :status, [:accepted, :shipped, :courier_shiped, :booked, :cancelled, :returned]

end
```

I have fired the below query in the rails console.

```
Order.select(:id,:status).group(:id,:status).count
```

getting the below errors in the rails console.

```
`exec_params': PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  function count(bigint, integer) does not exist (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(id,status) AS "count_id_status", id,status AS "...

HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts
```

need to retrieve all orders group by status column and count all the enums values in the rails console with their appropriate ids.

thanks!

Comment: An order can only have 1 status so... `Order.group(:status).count` [Docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-count).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following query to get the result, this will group data by status and return a count of ids having the same status. in Rails `select` with `count` does not work as count tries to execute the query immediately

```
 Order.select(:id, :status).group(:status).pluck('status, count(id)')
```

OR

```
Order.select('count(id), status').group(:status)
```

Comment: i have triggered above query Order.select('count(id), status').group(:status) and get result, [#<Order:0x00007f621eda7cf8 id: nil, status: "booked">,
 #<Order:0x00007f621eda7be0 id: nil, status: "accepted">,
 #<Order:0x00007f621eda7af0 id: nil, status: "oruried_ship">,
 #<Order:0x00007f621eda79d8 id: nil, status: "shipped">] , could be also print it's id.

Comment: hm, right. I just verified it on my machine and it does return nil for id, Have you tried the first one, is that working for you it's working for me but returning result in array format

Comment: I just modified the second query a bit to` Order.select('count(id) as id_count, status').group(:status).map(&:id_count)` and it returns me count, even though we are not able to see it, it exists you can access it for each record using an alias name